# How do you only receive 7 points for a upvote to your answer?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow

How does one only get 7 points for an upvote to your answer.

I guess I can understand only receiving 5 points but 7 points doesn't make sense.

Can anyone explain this?

[image]

---

**Edited: Snippet from Report**

```
-- 2010-11-03 rep +218  = 7443      
 2   4084193 (10)
 2   4092899 (10)
 1   4092899 (15)
 2   4092946 (10)
 2   4093025 (10)
 1   4093025 (15)
 2   4093025 (10)
 2   4092946 (10)
 2   4093025 (10)
 1   4018203 (15)
 1   4079458 (15)
 1   4090177 (15)
 2   4097871 (10)
 2   4097871 (10)
 2   4097871 (10)
 1   4093427 (15)
 2   4098656 (10)
 2   4098656 (10)
 2   4098656 (10)
 2   2867749 (10)
 1   4098656 (15)
 2   4098656 (10)
 2   2290473 (5)
 2   4099723 (10)
 2   4099857 (10)
 2   4099926 (10)
-- 2010-11-04 rep +290  = 7733
```

Comment: (for reference, the last one (4099926) is the one from the screenshot)

Comment: Finding out what today's score is after hitting the rep limit is never not interesting.  The number of ways it can permute are amazing.  The rep report has always been accurate for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will happen if you had already earned 193 points from votes on that day (i.e., you only have 7 points left that you could earn before hitting the 200 point rep cap).

You can check this at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: @jon B this was today and your report shows differently

Comment: @John - could you post a snippet from the rep audit showing today's activity?

Comment: @Jon B.  Posted a snippet in my question.

Comment: @John - did you downvote anything today that was then deleted? (Or were you downvoted today on anything that was deleted)

Comment: @Jon B. - Yes I was downvoted on something that I deleted.  Does that count against me? if so could you explain?

Comment: @John - you don't regain rep from deleted posts until your rep is manually recalculated (which is very rare). The reputation audit recalculates your rep from scratch, rather than using the "live" value. The recalc is your *true* score.

Comment: @John Also, you can request a recalc if you want one, to make your displayed rep on the site match the value from /reputation, but it looks like you'd actually lose 145 rep if you did that (probably from upvotes you had on deleted posts)

Answer (score 1):

If you downvoted three times, giving you -3, you will be capped at 197 for the day, according to the envelope and your displayed reputation score. The `/reputation` audit will not do this but cap you at full 200, "refunding" the downvotes.

Did you downvote anything that might now be deleted and not longer be included in your reputation audit?

(Disclaimer: It's been a while since I noticed this and I haven't checked recently if it's still the case.)

Comment: His rep audit shows no downvotes cast or received. If he downvoted three times and the post was deleted, that might do the trick.